# SQL Server trigger to Prevent Duplicate Entries from my TimeLog Table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a `TimeLog` table which took entries of employees in and out

But due to magnetic card reader machine it sometimes take multiple entries of duplicate data

The only difference in the entries is the few seconds (which might sometimes goes to different minutes)

Unique Identifiers:

- uid = user id
- type = in / out
- serial = Card Reader Number
- checktime = This will be a time difference which I need to check till one minute before

My trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[data_checkout] 
ON [dbo].[tblname]
AFTER INSERT
AS
   IF exists (select * 
              from [dbo].[tblname] t 
              inner join inserted i on datepart(DAY, t.checktime) = datepart(day,i.checktime)
                                    and datepart(MONTH, t.checktime) = datepart(MONTH, i.checktime) 
                                    and datepart(HOUR, t.checktime) = datepart(HOUR, i.checktime) 
                                    and datepart(MINUTE, t.checktime) = datepart(MINUTE, i.checktime)  
                                    and datepart(MINUTE, t.checktime) = datepart(MINUTE, DATEADD(minute, -1, i.checktime)) 
                                    and t.[uid] = i.[uid] 
                                    and t.[type] = i.[type] 
                                    and t.[serial] = i.[serial])
   begin
      rollback
      RAISERROR ('Duplicate Data', 16, 1);
   end
GO
```

Comment: I took help from the online forums and made this code. But it is not able to check.

Comment: There is **No NEED of Trigger** you can Use `Merge and Update ` statements in SQL SERVER

Comment: I don't think you need to qualify all of the datetime increments.  Focus your join on the UID, TYPE, Serial THEN t.timecheck >= i.timecheck -1 minute

Comment: Hello Ganesh, Thanks for Replying.
But The Insert is done through Magnetic Card Reader Software.

The Only way is through Trigger, Or any Functions which checks & Delete and can be Run Every few minutes interval

Comment: Hi Brad, Thanks for Replying.
The Problem is If the Magnetic card swipe the Machine by mistake makes 2-3 insert. There are more than one entries (i.e. Duplicate Entries). 
And The timecheck has the datetime format till Microseconds and the Only thing is different in all Duplicate Entries is few seconds of time in timecheck.